# What happens when you create new object inside a scope and exit

Tags: c++

If you create an object of any class inside a function and you push it into a vector, when you exit that function what happens to the object? It gets destroyed? If yes why? It shouldn't since we have a vector referring that object that will be used later in the code...

```
void class::foo(){
  //this class object has a private vector called 've'
  ve.push_back(aNotherClass(somearg));
  //watever
}//exit
void class::foo2(){
  aNotherClass an = ve.pop_back(); //example code not sure if it works.
  cout << an.getSomeAtrribute() << endl;
  //will print like 432042 something like this and I'm sure it is not that value. is it '->' or '.' ?
}
```

Comment: you dont say how `ve` is declared - assume it;s member variable, then sure it will not get destroyed

Comment: The object inside the vector is not the same object that you passed to `push_back`, and the result of `pop_back` is not the same object that was in the vector. If you're used to C# or Java, you should forget everything you know about "references".

Comment: I'm used to C# and its garbage collector. As Michael said I need to call delete if I use 'new'. And 'new' is what I need here. Put the pointer to the vector of the new object created outside the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local object created on stack (without using the new operator) will be destroyed. It is the language specification.

From the other side, the vector can be implemented in a way that it will create its own copy of an object. Thus allowing you to keep the data event after exit from the function.

Comment: It works if I refer in the vector that type of class is a pointer.
So, when I do someclass *c = new someclass(args); I'm creating this object outside the stack?

Comment: Yes, 'new' creates an object that will live until it is explicitly destroyed by a call to 'delete' or the process ends

Comment: @int3 an object of `someclass` is created on the heap by calling its constructor with the argument `args`. `new` then returns you this pointer. The `someclass` object lives on the heap; the pointer to that object is on the stack. The *pointer* will get destroyed at the end of the scope, but the object will not.

Answer (score 2):

`vector.push_back` makes a copy of the argument. The local object you created will be destroyed, but the vector will retain a copy. However, if that copy is just a copy of a pointer then you're in trouble.